# How to access azure k8s cluster without run Invoke Command?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubectl, azure-aks

I have an AKS cluster and it's private. I want to access it from my local and i added necessary commands for kubeconfig. Now, i can list pods with invoke command. But i want to access directly like kubectl get pods command. (i dont want do alias)

```
az aks command invoke \
  --resource-group rg-network-spokes \
  --name aks_dev_cluster \
  --command "kubectl get pods -A"
```

Comment: Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/private-clusters#options-for-connecting-to-the-private-cluster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your aks cluster is private, it means its controle plane is not exposed on internet and therefore you can not use kubectl to interact with the API without being into the same vnet as your cluster

[image]

You have a few [options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/private-clusters#options-for-connecting-to-the-private-cluster) to do so, such as :

- Create a VM in the same VNET as your cluster and install kubectl client
- Create a VPN to connect your computer on the aks's network

If you are starting with Azure, I would suggest going with the first option as setting up a VPN can be a bit more tedious.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your AKS cluster is private you must be accessing it via VPN right? You can connect to VPN to access the cluster over private network. You can download the kubeconfig via this command.

Pre-req [Azure Cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli) must be installed.

```
az aks get-credentials --resource-group my-rg --name my-aks --file my-aks-kubeconfig-ss
```

It will generate a kubeconfig for you with name my-aks-kubeconfig-ss. You can copy this config and paste inside .kube/ folder or your choice. You can access AKS cluster from Lens via UI mode.

2. Second option is to use [lens](https://k8slens.dev/).

Install lens. After installation lens press ctrl + shift + A and a windows will open asking for kubeconfig. Copy the content from my-aks-kubeconfig-ss and paste it here. Bingo your cluster is added inside Lens.

Comment: OP's issue is not being into the same vnet as aks cluster, not "how to download a kubeconfig file?"

Comment: Will, quetion does not mention about vnet or anything. It only states the cluster is private so I just explained possible scenarios how that private cluster can be accessed via different options.

Answer (score -2):

You can download the kubeconfig file in this path "/home/.kube/config" and now you are good to go.

Or, Use Kubernetes Lens to manage from a UI.

Comment: Please explain how this will work with a private cluster not exposed to the Internet.

Comment: it does not solve OP problem